# Insert constructed string into Vec in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

Right now I am writing a program where I am updating a `Vec` with a string constructed based on conditions in a for loop. A (very contrived) simplified form of what I'm trying to do is the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec!["_"; 5];
    for (i, chr) in "abcde".char_indices() {
        arr[i] = &chr.to_string().repeat(3);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error `temporary value dropped while borrowed`. Any pointers on what to do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lifetime of `arr` is the scope of the `main` method while `chr.to_string()` is only valid in the body of the for loop. Assigning it causes the error.

You can avoid this problem by using a `Vec<String>` instead of `Vec<&str>`.

```
fn main() {
  let mut arr = vec!["_".to_string(); 5];
  for (i, chr) in "abcde".char_indices() {
    arr[i] = chr.to_string().repeat(3);
  }
}
```

Here we see the String `"_".to_string()` copied five times (which is not very efficient). I suspect this is not the case in your real code.

Comment: While this solved the OP's problem, it should be noted that @wasmup's answer produces the same result using more idiomatic Rust

Answer (score 5):

Using String try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=374fc70d4a93a47f274a980fc6529c7e) one liner too:

```
let arr: Vec<String> = "abcde".chars().map(|c| c.to_string().repeat(3)).collect();
```

Output:

```
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the `String` that you are creating *have* to be owned by someone, otherwise they end up being dropped. As the compiler detects that this drop occurs while your arrays still holds references to them, it will complain.

You need to think about who needs to own these values. If your eventual array is the natural place for them to live, just `move` them there:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut arr = Vec::with_capacity(5);
    for (i, chr) in "abcde".char_indices() {
        arr.push(chr.to_string().repeat(3));
    }
}
```

If you absolutely need an array of `&str`, you still need to maintain these values 'alive' for at least as long as the references themselves:

```rust
fn i_only_consume_refs(data: Vec<&String>) -> () {}

fn main() {
    let mut arr = Vec::with_capacity(5);
    for (i, chr) in "abcde".char_indices() {
        arr.push(chr.to_string().repeat(3));
    }
    let refs = arr.iter().collect();
    i_only_consume_refs(refs)
}
```

Here, we are still moving all the created `String`s to the vector `arr`, and THEN taking references on its elements. This way, the vector of references is valid as long as `arr` (who owns the strings) is.

TL;DR: Someone needs to own these `String`s while you keep references to them. You cannot create temporary strings, and only store the reference, otherwise you will have a reference to a dropped value, which is very bad indeed, and the compiler will not let you do that.

Comment: Where does the move happen in the first example exactly? I'm not saying the code is wrong, but as someone not super familiar with Rust I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `arr` only holds references, and the strings inside must be owned elsewhere. A possible fix is to simply leak the transient String you created inside the loop.

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec!["_"; 5];
    for (i, chr) in "abcde".char_indices() {
        arr[i] = Box::leak(Box::new(chr.to_string().repeat(3)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Leaking means that the referenced `Box` will never be removed from memory later on.